# Is it possible to define a structure of differentiable manifold on the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Is it possible to define a structure of differentiable (smooth) manifold on the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ ?

Has it been done in the literature?

In textbooks, only the Banach case is treated, but the Hilbert cube has countable dimension, and a vector space with countable dimension is not complete (although the Hilbert cube is complete, because of compacity), this is a problem for the tangent space. However, can something be done? maybe with some restrictions?

Comment: Isn't it part of the definition of a manifold that every point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an n-dimensional ball?

Comment: I am actually asking if this definition can be extended to this case. there already exists Banach manifolds, which are infinite dimensional. Hibert cube manifolds are defined here: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1970-76-06/S0002-9904-1970-12660-X/S0002-9904-1970-12660-X.pdf but i am not sure if it helps

Comment: I've seen references to "Hilbert cube manifolds", of which the Hilbert cube must be one, but this was in a topological context, and I don't know whether there's a reasonable notion of differentiability in this context.

Comment: A convenient class is maybe all restrictions of differentiable maps definined on nbds of the Hilbert cube, thought as a subset of a Hilbert space.

Comment: Cross posted from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511341/is-it-possible-to-define-a-structure-of-differentiable-manifold-on-the-hilbert-c

Comment: @ScottMorrison: I migrated the MSE version here. Please merge.

Comment: You can find a useful method of determining if a topological space can be given a manifold structure in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds." On page 21 he gives the Smooth Manifold Construction Lemma. Basically, you need to know that your space satisfies the basic topological properties (paracompact, second countable) and then you need an idea of what the atlas should be. This lemma tells you exactly what must be checked. In your case you have the topological properties, but no atlas. Also, there's the issue of infinite dimensionality.

Comment: "...but the Hilbert cube has countable dimension, and a vector space with countable dimension is not complete..." The Hilbert cube is not a (topological) vector space, as it is compact, while all TVS have got to be unbounded. You're confusing the Hamel dimension with the topological dimension.

Answer (score 4):

In other words, the question is if the Hilbert cube can be homeomorphic to a differentiable Banach manidold. The answer is no, not even a topological manifold modelled on a topological vector space.  Since the Hilbert cube is compact, in that  case the model space would be locally compact, hence finite dimensional. 
But it is not the case of the Hilbert cube, because (for instance) it  contains spheres of any finite dimension.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking whether one can define differentiable Hilbert cube manifolds, similarly to topological Hilbert cube manifolds? Your answer does not rule this out.

Comment: The question "Is it possible to define a structure of differentiable (smooth) manifold on the Hilbert cube" has a clear meaning to me (is there a differentiable atlas on it compatible with its topology), but maybe you are right, especially reading the OP's comment. In this case  the main question would be Andreas Blass': what's a reasonable notion of differentiable maps on the Hilbert cube.

Comment: yes, i asked a new question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143765/can-we-define-smooth-diffeomorphisms-on-the-hilbert-cube-0-1-mathbbn-ha