# Are there examples of compact infinite dimensional manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Are there known examples of compact infinite dimensional manifolds?

The word "manifold" is important.

Comment: How do you define an infinite dimensional manifold? Is it modelled on the countable product of lines?

Comment: If this is your definition, then the answer is no, because if $K$ is a compact subset of a manifold $Y$ modelled on the countable product of lines, then $Y$ and $Y-K$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: just modelled on a vector space. like Banach manifold, Frechet manifold.

Comment: Any separable Frechet (or Banach) space is homeomorphic to the countable product of lines, so my answer above applies.

Comment: It seems to me Pietro Majer already addressed this in his answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/143737/2926 Right?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: What if $K$ is empty, or $K$ is a finite set of points? Are $K$ and $Y-K$ homeomorphic?

Comment: @todd : Pietro Majer seems to reply indirectly to it. so the reply seems to be no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The empty space is a manifold of any dimension.

No, seriously, let's assume that "manifold" means a Hausdorff space in which every point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of a topological vector space. If the manifold is compact and nonempty then the vector space must be locally compact. As far as I know, that makes it finite-dimensional.

Comment: Feeling of deja vu... Ah yes: http://mathoverflow.net/a/143737/2926

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Compact Hilbert cube manifolds, for instance.

Comment: wrong. the Hilbert cube is not a manifold http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143724/is-it-possible-to-define-a-structure-of-differentiable-manifold-on-the-hilbert-c

Comment: perhaps you mean it is not a _differentiable_ manifold.